# math.net installation for F#

Tags: f#, installation, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I am quite new to F# and am trying to install math.net on Ubuntu 13.04. The following page recommends using the Package Manager Console to install on Linux 64

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Numerics.MKL.Linux-x64/

but I am puzzled by the fact that in my understand the PMC is only available in VS, hence in Windows only. Any suggestion? Or maybe I should not rely on this library, and a different one is the standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NuGet gallery recommends PMC on every page. It doesn't seem to be aware that you are on linux, where PMC is not available(*).

You'll want to look at the instructions in [this link](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/nuget-faq#Can_I_use_NuGet_outside_of_Visual_Studio%3f).

I can't tell if the package in question is the one you want–that depends of course on what you expect it to do for you :)

(*) I'm on a Mac. I feel your pain.

Comment: Primarily interested in ease of use at this stage. I am not overly concerned with performance, although having the implementation work with ATLAS or MKL would be great. 

One open issue I am still exploring is the level and quality of support of F# on Linux. Poor support would be off-putting.

Comment: I never use "PMC", just straight command line nuget.exe. On my mac as on windows, it is the same procedure to install packages. another command to know apart from CR answer is "nuget i pathto\packages.config -o pathto\Packages" to restore.

Comment: ps : pretty chuffed to see some Gappy using f#

Answer (score 2):

It seems using F# from Ubuntu got much more straightforward in 14.04, see [fsharp.org](http://fsharp.org/use/linux/).

For Math.NET Numerics in F# you then only need the `MathNet.Numerics.FSharp` package, and `MathNet.Numerics` which the former depends on. Those packages should support recent F# and Mono on Linux.

I do not recommend to use our Linux MKL NuGet package as we cannot update it anymore (lack of Linux license right now). Instead consider to build from source - or better, help us provide proper Linux ATLAS builds and packages :)

Assuming you have Mono installed and a local copy of nuget.exe (sic!):

```
mono nuget.exe install MathNet.Numerics.FSharp -Pre -OutputDirectory packages
```

Or just [download the assemblies in a zip file](https://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/releases/view/119109).